# MySql Prepared Statement to Convert Row Values to Columns

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to follow the example from this site:
http://vitobotta.com/mysql-generate-column-names-dynamically-from-row-values/

I have a table with like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| MessageId  | ProcessDate  | FieldName | FieldValue |
+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
|         18 | 2015-12-04   |  data     | 101110101  |
|         18 | 2015-12-04   |   type    | binary     |
|         19 | 2015-12-04   |   type    | integer    |
|         19 | 2015-12-04   |  data     | 34         |
+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

What I want is something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| MessageId  | ProcessDate  | type      |    data    |
+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
|         18 | 2015-12-04   |  binar    | 101110101  |
|         19 | 2015-12-04   |  integer  | 34         |
+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

My Code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_results;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_results AS
SELECT r.`MessageId`, r.`ProcessDate`, r.`TransportType`, d.`FieldName`, d.`FieldValue`
FROM 
returnmessages r, decodedmessagessummaryrecord s, decodedmessagesdetailrecord d
WHERE r.`Id` = s.`ReturnMessagesId`
AND s.`Id` = d.`DecodedMessagesSummaryRecordId`
AND r.`MobileId` = "35"
LIMIT 10;

SELECT CONCAT('
  SELECT MessageId, ProcessDate, TransportType, ', field_value, '
  FROM tmp_results'
)
INTO @variable1
FROM
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName=''',field_name,''' THEN FieldValue
END), ''-'' AS "', col_name,'"')) field_value
FROM(
  SELECT field_name, field_name as col_name
  FROM(SELECT DISTINCT FieldName AS field_name FROM tmp_results) AS fieldnames
  ) field_with_col_names
) result;
PREPARE prepstate FROM @s;

EXECUTE prepstate;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepstate;
```

Which returns an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tmp_results' at line 3

I'm not really sure what's going wrong at this point.

Comment: Leave a space in front of FROM  `'FROM tmp_results'` since it will directly glue to the value before it

Comment: I tried adding a space but it doesn't seem to respect it. I'm still getting the same error. `SELECT CONCAT('
SELECT MessageId, ProcessDate, TransportType, ', field_value , ' FROM tmp_results'
)`

Comment: sqlfiddle some sample data

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b0aa/4/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b0aa/4/0)

Comment: Something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b0aa/15 ? Just to make sure

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for.  The problem is that there may be more than just the 2 values in the FieldName column so I'd like it to be more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when FieldName = ''',
      FieldName,
      ''' then FieldValue  end) AS ',
      '`',FieldName,'`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from tmp_results;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MessageId, ProcessDate, TransportType, ', @sql, ' from tmp_results 
group by MessageId');

SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b0aa/32)